# What is the status of the Sparkle framework?

Tags: macos, sparkle

The latest beta is 2 years old. Most blog comments on Andy's website too.

Is there a new version, living somewhere else? Or an alternative to Sparkle as a whole?

It works for me now, I'm just wondering if there are going to be any further updates to Sparkle, or the promising SparkleCaster app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very much alive. See the Q&A site for the Sparkle framework [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/sparkle/). You can ask your question directly to Andy and he'll answer you pretty quickly. The git repository [here](http://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle) is actively maintained, too.